# React Native Class cannot accept props, unable to pass variables?

Tags: react-native, function, class, variables

I am having a difficult time passing variables to a class in React-Native.  I can send variables as 'props' between functions, whereby usage of the 'props' parameter in the function will accept variables pushed forward from another function, such as:

```
Details.js

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

const Details = (props) => {

  //works fine, all 3 variables are passed from the previous calling function...
  console.log('DETAILS props called name: ' + props.name);
  console.log('DETAILS props called email address: ' + props.address);
  console.log('DETAILS props called password: ' + props.password);

//SEND THESE SAME VARIABLES ONWARD TO A COMPONENT/CLASS, CALLED 'VIDEO.JS'...
Actions.push('video', { name: props.name, address: props.address, password: props.password })

}

export default Details
```

HOWEVER, the same functionality is not possible with a class, for example:

```
Video.js

import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default class Broadcast extends Component {

  //NOT FUNCTIONAL...ERROR THROWN
  console.log('VIDEO props called name: ' + props.name);
  console.log('VIDEO props called email address: ' + props.address);
  console.log('VIDEO props called password: ' + props.password);

  goToWeb = () => {
  Actions.browser()
  }

  //...other various functions

}
```

Is it necessary to declare a 'props' parameter in the class someplace?  Is it even possible at all to accept variables in a class from a calling function in this way...or is there some special way to set it up?  Thanks in advance for any advice, React Native is extremely confusing to me.  There is obviously something I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **this** to access props in class components

Try:

```
console.log('VIDEO props called name: ' + this.props.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it still throws an error.  I get an 'unexpected token' error using the "console.log('VIDEO props called name: ' + this.props.name)" command.

Comment: Hi! Did you put "this.props." in every prop?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been busy working.  I am not sure I understand your question...what do you mean "in every prop"...?  Thank you.